# How do I combine Hex reading from text files with a state machine

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to implement a state machine with hex reading from text file. However, I am stuck without ideas on how to proceed. 
There will be four cases, the first two cases outputs a sequence of data acting as the header. Which is idle sequence and start sequence. The 3rd case is my actual hex reading from text file data. It reads the hex data and transmit out bit by bit. The last case sends a tail sequence bit.
For the first cycle, it will send the inverted version of the data. The 2nd cycle would send the actual data. The last cycle sends the inverted version. Before starting with a new line,

Edit: What I mean by cycle is on the first loop of the 4 cases

Currently, I am trying to test whether it could run for the first 3 cycles before moving on to implement going to next line. 
I also need to figure out how to refresh the inline data to read back the same line. I am guessing `inline := new string'(inline.all);`

```
For example my text file has AA 00 on the first line. BB 11 on 2nd line
Using
Idle seq of "010"
start seq of "1110"
tail seq of "11000"
For first cycle at first case it reads in inverted Idle, next case reads inverted start seq then 3rd case inverted of AA 00 and last case inverted of tail seq. 
Then would add a count to sequence and restart with 2nd cycle this time sending actual data. Then 3rd cycle go back to inverted sequence and exit. Before moving on to next line
So.. ( , represent each new case) 
count = 1;
101,0001,0101 1111, 00111. 
Count = 2 condition (send actual data)
010, 1110, 1010 000, 11000
Count = 3
101,0001,0101 1111, 00111. and move on to next line
count = 1 (Reset to 1)
101, 0001, 01000100, 0011
count = 2
010, 1110, 10111011, 11000
count = 3
101, 0001, 01000100, 0011
```

I tried implementing case together with my hread function while I was able to view the first cycle. I was unable to read from text file during my 2nd cycle and the program stops there.
It seems I shouldn't open the file one more time to read again. 
I am guessing I need to shift my file open and read statements before the case however when I do so I wasn't able to output any data in my first cycle cases.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_textio.all;
LIBRARY STD;
USE STD.textio.all;
USE IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity readtext is
port (  
IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1: OUT    std_logic;
);
end readtext;

ARCHITECTURE arch_name OF readtext IS
signal clock,endoffile : std_logic := '0';
signal readdatainput : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

signal startSeq : std_logic_vector(0 to 3):= "1110"; 
signal tailSeq : std_logic_vector(0 to 4):= "11000"; 
signal idleSeq : std_logic_vector(0 to 2):= "010"; 

signal Bitreading : std_logic;

signal next_dataSendState: std_logic_vector(0 to 1);


BEGIN

clock <= not (clock) after 0.5 ms;   

reading:
process
    file   infile    : text is in  "A.txt";
    variable inline    : line; --line number declaration
    file file_RESULTS : text;
    variable inputdata : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    variable TFSeqCount: integer range 1 to 3;

begin
wait until rising_edge(clock);
    case next_dataSendState is
    when "00"=> 
    for i in idleSeq'range loop
    IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= not idleSeq(i);
    if (TFSeqCount=2) then
    IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= idleSeq(i);
    end if;
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    end loop;           
    next_dataSendState<= "10";

    when "10"=> --staRT
    for i in startSeq'range loop
    IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= not startSeq(i);
    if (TFSeqCount=2) then
    IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= startSeq(i);
    end if;
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    end loop;
    next_dataSendState<= "01";

    when "01"=>  --transmit
    while not endfile(infile) loop  --open file 
    readline(infile, inline);
         while inline.all'length /= 0 loop --check if line have values
         hread (inline, inputdata);
         readdatainput <= inputdata;
         for i in inputdata'range loop
         Bitreading <= inputdata(i);
         IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= not inputdata(i);
         if (TFSeqCount=2) then
         IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= inputdata(i);
         end if;
         wait until rising_edge(clock);
         end loop; --end of bitrange
        end loop; --end of line
       end loop; --end of file  

     file_close(infile);  

    next_dataSendState<= "11";

    when "11"=> 
    for i in tailSeq'range loop
    IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= not tailSeq(i);
    if (TFSeqCount=2) then
    IN_SRX2_BPSKDAT1 <= tailSeq(i);
    end if;
    wait until rising_edge(clock);
    end loop;   
    TFSeqCount:=TFSeqCount+1;           
    next_dataSendState<= "00";
    when others =>
    next_dataSendState<="00";   
    end case;




end process reading;
endoffile <='1';         
END ARCHITECTURE arch_name;


First cycle reads fine. The data isnt reading on 2nd cycle. I am guessing I have to shift the 
while not endfile(infile) loop  --open file 
readline(infile, inline);
while inline.all'length /= 0 loop 
to be above the case somewhere. Additionally I gotta save the line of data as a string to use for 2nd case.
```

Comment: You need to clarify - this is for simulation only? None of this will work on real hardware.

Comment: I am testing on simulation currently.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Here that includes delimiting what lines are actually in A.txt, as code that will analyze (compile). Your description of your problem is confusing including the term 'cycle' as in "First cycle reads fine. ..." Note that once you execute `file_close(infile);` there's nothing that opens the file for a subsequent 'cycle', which should generate an error when evaluating `endfile(infile)`  as the condition in your while loop (show that error message).

Comment: Also see [this answer describing endfile on a closed file as an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267035/is-there-anyway-to-read-through-a-file-multiple-times-in-vhdl-using-std-textio/32267795#32267795). The file_open procedure was added in -1997.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there anyway to read through a file multiple times in vhdl using std textio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267035/is-there-anyway-to-read-through-a-file-multiple-times-in-vhdl-using-std-textio)

Comment: Don't open the file when declared - `file infile: text; -- is in "A.txt";`. Open the file as the first statement in choice "01" of the case statement - `file_open(infile, "A.txt", READ_MODE);`. Also where TFSeqCount is incremented prevent overflow (bounds check error during simulation). Then [when simulated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LW4h.jpg) it'll work.